# arrange items respecting order

Tags: python, cycle, reorderlist

I have a list of elements that I need to rearrange cyclically such that I keep their order. The problem seems quite simple but I can't figure out a smart way to code it. Say you have elements

```
1 2 3 4 o o o 5 6 7
```

The o's are always contiguous in the array, but I need to change this array so that the o's (which are not necessarily of a different type) are last in a cyclic way:

```
5 6 7 1 2 3 4 o o o
```

The problem is that the o's may be also contiguous in a cyclic way. For example,

```
o o 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 o
```

Is there a smart way to do this? I've been looking at `cycle` from itertools, but as of now I don't have a working implementation as what I did is unable to handle the last case.

**UPDATE**

I have a first working implementation:

```
def arrange2(nodes, contiguous):

    arranged = []
    size = len(nodes)

    if nodes[0] in contiguous:

        # obtain the id of the last interface node in nodes
        id = None
        for i in range(1, len(nodes)):
            if nodes[i] not in contiguous:
                id = i
                break

        # copy nodes to new list starting from the first node past id
        for i in range(id, id + size):
            arranged += [nodes[i % size]]
    else:

        # obtain the id of the last interface node in nodes
        id = None
        for i in range(size - 1, -1, -1):
            if nodes[i] in contiguous:
                id = i
                break

        # copy nodes to new list starting from the first node past id
        for i in range(id+1, id + size+1):
            arranged += [nodes[i % size]]

    return arranged


print(arrange2([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [5, 6]))
```

This prints
    [7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

Comment: Could you provide more real examples ? I don't understand why contiguous needs to be `[5,6]` and not just 6.

Comment: You can take any set of contiguous numbers from that list. I took `[5,6]` as an example, but you could take `[9, 10, 1, 2]` which is contiguous in cyclic way, or `[10, 1, 2]`, etc.

Comment: But what's the difference between "I want 2 at the end" and "I want 10,1,2" at the end ? If you put 2 at the end, and conserve the order, then you will have "10,1,2" at the end.

Comment: All the contiguous elements need to be rearranged so that they are at the end of the list. So if my contiguous elements are `[9, 10, 1, 2]` then the list should look like `[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2]`. If the contiguous list is `[10, 1, 2]` then the result would be `[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2]`.

Comment: The two results are exactly the same, which proves my point.

Comment: Can there be duplicate items? E.g. `arrange2([2,1,3,1,1,5], [1,1])`. Or is the list always guaranteed to have unique values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, basing on you implementation I have this:

```
def arrange(nodes: list, contigious: list) -> list:
    first_contigious = nodes.index(contigious[0])
    last_contigious = nodes.index(contigious[-1])

    if first_contigious < last_contigious:
        # Normal situation
        return nodes[last_contigious+1:] + nodes[:first_contigious] + contigious
    else:
        # The contigious part is cycling
        return nodes[last_contigious+1:first_contigious] + contigious
```

---

EDIT, after clarification in the comments, that the contigious collection doesn't have to be ordered I have this:

```
def arrange(nodes: list, contigious: set) -> list:
    # Make sure that contigious is a set
    contigious = set(contigious)

    # Return if all nodes are in contigious or nodes are empty
    if len(contigious.intersection(nodes)) == len(nodes) or not len(nodes):
        return nodes

    if nodes[0] in contigious and nodes[-1] in contigious:
        # The contigious part is split and present on the beggining and the 
        # end of the nodes list
        cut = next(i for i, x in enumerate(nodes) if x not in contigious)
        # I move the nodes from the beggining to the end
        return nodes[cut:] + nodes[:cut]
    else:
        # The contigious part is somewhere in the middle of the nodes list
        # I need to find the end of contigious sequence
        cut = next(i for i, x in enumerate(reversed(nodes)) if x in contigious)
        cut = len(nodes) - cut
        return nodes[cut:] + nodes[:cut]
```

Note: It's your job to make sure that the contigious elements are indeed next to each other and not scattered in 3 or more groups.

Comment: This fails: `print(arrange([400, 259, 260, 401], [400, 401]))`

Comment: @aaragon That's because `[400, 401]` is not a subsequence of `[400, 259, 260, 401, 400, 259, 260, 401, ...]`. This works fine `arrange([400, 259, 260, 401], [401, 400])`.

Comment: My bad @Maciek, it seems it's alright, because the actual order I gave is wrong. This works: `print(arrange([400, 259, 260, 401], [401, 400]))` prints `[259, 260, 401, 400]` which is correct.

Comment: This breaks too: `print(arrange([4, 1, 2, 5], [4, 5]))`. The problem is that the contiguous array that you pass may not be in order. So in this example it works when you pass contiguous as `[5,4]` but not as `[4,5]` and it should work in both cases.

Comment: Oh, so the second argument should be a `set` to not confuse anyone :) Ok, so let me see how to fix it...

Comment: @aaragon take a look now. I hope that it's not a problem that I'm using Python3?

Comment: Python 3 is perfect. It's interesting how you can specify the type the function signature, I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: @aargon yeah, that's very cool and unfortunately not that popular feature of Python3 :) especially if you work with a good IDE like PyCharm, that understands the annotations and helps you out with code completion and error checking using it.

Answer (score 1):

Using the fact that all the "o" are continuous, I implemented:

```
def rearrange(l):
    i=0
    found=False
    while i<len(l):
        if l[i]=="o":
            found=True
            l=l[i+1:]+l[:i+1]
            i=0
        else:
            if found:
                break
            i+=1
    return l
```

You iterate through the list. At the first occurrence `i` of an "o", you split the list and inverse it.
`l=["o","o",1,2,3,"o"]` is "split" in `["o"] (l[:i+1])` and `["o",1,2,3,"o"] (l[i+1:])`. Invert the two part and put them back together, you obtain a new list `["o",1,2,3,"o","o"]`.
This way, the "o" are pushed to the end.

You then start again with the new list. When the new list doesn't start by an 'o' (`found` is True and `l[i]!="o"`), it means your done.

```
>>>l=[1,2,3,4,"o","o","o",5,6,7]
>>>print(rearrange(l))
[5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 'o', 'o', 'o']


>>>l=["o","o",1,2,3,"o"]
>>>print(rearrange(l))
[1, 2, 3, 'o', 'o', 'o']
```

---

To provide a list of contiguous element instead of "o", this small change should work:

```
def rearrange(l,contiguous):
    i=0
    found=False
    while i<len(l):
        if l[i] in contiguous:
            ...
```

Comment: But looking at you update I guess I took the "o" a bit too literally.

Comment: Is there a less verbose way to do it? Also, look at the example I gave, I have a list of values that are contiguous, whereas you're only checking for 'o'.

Comment: Yes, it seems this works. So far is the best answer I got.

Comment: The IDs, though the are not necessarily in order, are unique.